# Not getting message on Subscribing to Channel in PubNub Javascript (Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, messaging, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I am published to a channel, message got published.. while subscribing to channel, My callback function is not getting triggered..
here is the code..

```
Pubnub.publish(
{
    message: { 
        signal: 'switch',
        state: 0
    },
    channel: 'myChannel'
},
function (status, response) {
    if (status.error) {
        console.log(status)
    } else {
        console.log("message Published w/ timetoken", response.timetoken)
    }
}
);

Pubnub.subscribe({
channels: ['myChannel'],
message : function(m){ alert(m) }

});
```

Can anyone please help me how to trigger this event.... Also I am stuck to save this published message in global js variable.

Comment: You need to subscribe before you publish.

Comment: The same thing as you told I subscribed in node js and the server is keep on listening,  published in angularjs.. but message event is not triggering..

Comment: I only see the code above. Can you provide the Node code. Which versions of Angular and Node SDKs?